# Using delete keyword on storage variables

Tags: solidity, remix

Here is an implementation:
I am running delete keyword on two different struct variables. on storage variable remix gives an error but not on memory. Why is this so?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract myContract
{
    struct abc {
        uint8[] m;
        uint a ;
    }

    function myFucn() returns(bool)
    {
        abc storage b;   
        abc memory a;
        delete a;
        delete b; // error unary operator cannot be applied to storage pointer.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is not mistake in your post? From my undertanding, it would be a that you would not be able to delete.

Comment: Yes I wasn't but why?

Comment: Because, from my understanding, I may be wrong, you can't delete memory variable because they don't have pointers (they are not actually stored), but storage variable have a pointer (obvisouly), like i C language.

Answer (score 7):

```
abc storage b;
```

is declaring an uninitialized storage pointer, it should be used to point to some variable in storage.

It is not possible to *delete* a storage pointer, even if it has been initialized, as stated in the [solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#data-location). Deleting it would "reset" the pointer, but there is no sensible location for it to point to, so it is not allowed.

However, if you had a state variable (which is implicitly stored in storage), you could delete this directly e.g. the following is allowed

```
contract MyContract {
    string myStorageVariable;

    function removeTheVariable(string strArg) public {
        myStorageVariable = strArg;
        delete myStorageVariable;
    }
}
```