# Understanding more about delete keyword in solidity

Tags: solidity

The blockchain is an immutable, append-only transaction set. 
I have the following questions regarding `delete` keyword -

Then what is the purpose of `delete`keyword in solidity?

Is it only for variables stored in memory?

Is it possible to `delete` variables stored in storage and stack?

What are all the possible cases in which `delete` keyword should be used and where it should not be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`delete` is actually not really deletion at all - it's only assigning a *default* value back to variables. It does not make difference whether the variable is in memory or in storage.

For example, issuing a `delete` to a `uint` variable simply sets the variable's value to `0`.

`delete` will also give a bit of your used gas back - this is to encourage deleting variables after their data is no longer needed so the size of the blockchain would stay a bit smaller. Note that you can never regain more gas than what your current transaction is using.

You can read more about `delete` here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html?highlight=delete#delete

Answer (score 0):

See the answer of stackexchange
[Short description about delete](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/35993/40417)

And also follow the link of soldityreadthedocs.