# Clearing storage struct array with Solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, storage, struct

We're implementing a Lottery where a player can buy multiple tickets.

A ticket is defined with a struct and they are being kept in a `storage struct[]`:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Lottery {

    struct Ticket {
        address payable playerAddress;
        uint256 potAtParticipation;
        uint256 potWithStake;
    }

    Ticket[] tickets;

    constructor() {
       _createLottery();
    }
```

After a specific block a winner gets determined and the lottery should be restarted. Therefore, we'd like to reset the `tickets`:

```
  function _createLottery() internal {
      tickets = new Ticket[](0); //this is not working as intended
    }
}
```

We're now facing the issue, that the code above does not empty/reset the array, due the combination of being a storage struct array - which makes sense.

But here we're stuck. What other approaches are there to accomplish a reset of our tickets?

We've seen ideas such as use `delete` ([Understanding more about delete keyword in solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58495/understanding-more-about-delete-keyword-in-solidity)) and `pop`. But it seems not to be doing quite the job / feels too complicated.

What would be the best practice/a good approach here?

Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: Does this help? [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why `delete` should feel complicated.

```
    function _createLottery() internal {
      delete tickets;
    }
```

It essentially resets the whole storage array by 'zeroing' out all data that you have entered and setting `.length` to 0.